# Which Lubuntu Next LXQt distro is the current one?

Tags: lubuntu, distro-recommendation

I want to download the current Lubuntu Next 17.10 version with LXQt, but I found two folders on its servers.

Why are they separate, when they appear to be the same: 17.10 == artful.

[image]

They contains distros with different "last modified" times (the dates are same). Please help me to make a choice. I need the one with LXQt.

Comment: Post address to us, I'm interested on it!

Comment: @Redbob here is the folder with lubuntu next releases: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu-next/

Comment: Tks! In my opinion, two directories have same content. Just redundancy. I'll test 17.10 to see if LXQt will be there.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this. It isn't a bug report or a problem with the development version of Ubuntu, partly as it's not what we probably mean by "a problem" in that context, but also as it applies to the download directories for all releases, on the `releases`, `cdimage`, and `old-releases` servers and mirrors. The version number and codename directories are always equivalent. The other aspect of the question--about which one has LXQt--is something I think we'd consider on-topic, and may warrant an answer on how the relevant distinction is between the `lubuntu` and `lubuntu-next` directories.

Comment: Look, HerrFelix, it's [LXQt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v4uqnml4rpw4kso/Sele%C3%A7%C3%A3o_125.png?dl=0)! Lubuntu turned from water to wine!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see from the MD5SUMS that they're in fact the same. Both http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu-next/releases/17.10/alpha-2/MD5SUMS and http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu-next/releases/artful/alpha-2/MD5SUMS contain:

```
76f9cebe11b205e865a5f3c838d570b7 *artful-desktop-amd64.iso
0e06c43341501bad8b5f0d73a8ec3524 *artful-desktop-i386.iso
```

The same goes for the `beta-1` MD5SUMS (with different values, of course).

It's convenient to be able to refer to a release by both version and codename. I don't know about LXQT, but [the ISO manifest](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu-next/releases/artful/beta-1/lubuntu-next-17.10-beta1-desktop-amd64.manifest) lists the following `lxqt` packages:

```
liblxqt-globalkeys-ui0:amd64    0.11.1-2
liblxqt-globalkeys0:amd64   0.11.1-2
liblxqt0:amd64  0.11.1-2
lxqt-about  0.11.1-2
lxqt-admin  0.11.1-2
lxqt-common 0.11.2-2
lxqt-config 0.11.1-4
lxqt-globalkeys 0.11.1-2
lxqt-notificationd  0.11.1-2
lxqt-openssh-askpass    0.11.1-2
lxqt-panel  0.11.1-3
lxqt-policykit  0.11.1-2
lxqt-powermanagement    0.11.1-2
lxqt-qtplugin:amd64 0.11.1-2build1
lxqt-runner 0.11.1-2
lxqt-session    0.11.1-6
lxqt-sudo   0.11.1-2
```

Make of that what you will.

Comment: I'd go even further: the two directories are likely *identical* because one is a symbolic link to the other.